# Don't know what node() is doing here

Tags: xslt

It's a part of a longer XSLT, which I have to comment. Does anyone know, what's happening here especially with the value-of select="node()"?

```
<xsl:template match="type">                                                 
    <xsl:element name="attribute">                                          
        <xsl:attribute name="NAME">type</xsl:attribute>                     
        <xsl:attribute name="VALUE"><xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
<xsl:attribute name="VALUE"><xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
```

selects the content of the XML element which is called "type" and inserts it as the attribute value of the attribute called "VALUE" of the element called "attribute".

You might want to rethink your naming conventions :-).

Comment: I'd wish, I could rename it, but it's not my XSLT, so I'm not able to rename it :D thank you! :)

Comment: Please do not forget to mark the answer you found the most helpful with the tick on the left. This prevents other users from spending time thinking about questions that are sufficiently answered already.

Answer (score 1):

Well `xsl:value-of` always creates a text node, with `select="node()"` a text node with the string value of the first child node of the context node (which is a `type` element in your template) in XSLT 1.0 or with the concatenation of the string values of all child nodes in XSLT 2.0.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests.